# Need help making a list accept multiple user inputs without removing the input before it

Tags: c#, winforms, collections

I need help making a Score Calculator for my class. The inputs for the scores can't be preset and it has to add up all previous inputs while increasing the count number.

For example say I entered 23 into the text box and hit enter then typed in 45 i need my program to keep the 23 and add it to the 45 and it needs to repeat this for as long as the user inputs numbers.

I know it needs to be a collection and i have the basis for it down i just need the code that will save the input from before and add it to the new one and save that total to add it to the next input.

This is my attempt at solving this problem:

```
 List<decimal> score = new List<decimal>();
        score.Add(scoreInput);
        decimal scoreTotal = 0;
        decimal scoreHolder = 0;
        foreach (decimal d in score)
        {

            scoreTotal = scoreHolder + scoreInput;
            scoreHolder = scoreInput;
            scoreInput = 0;
            txtTotal.Text = scoreTotal.ToString("");
            txtCount.Text = score.Count.ToString("");
            txtScore.Clear();
            txtScore.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: Can you declare a variable `sum`?

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you post a little code?

Comment: You need to provide more details like whether this is a Web Forms, Windows Forms, Console or some other type of application. Also, you should show some code for what you have already tried. People are quite willing to offer advice, but don't want to feel like they are doing your homework for you.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an event handler for the KeyDown event, and use a code like the following:

```
private void tbEntry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Decimal entry;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (Decimal.TryParse(tbEntry.Text, out entry))
        {
            score.Add(entry);
        }

        tbResult.Text = score.Sum(s => s).ToString();
        tbEntry.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This is one way of doing what you want to achieve.

EDIT:

This is assuming that you have your variable "score" declared as a member of your Form:

```
private  List<decimal> score = new List<decimal>();
```

Cheers